# Update the axis labels with rChart

Tags: r, rcharts, googlevis

I just discovered rChart and googleVis and i want to thank developers for their job.
My problem is simple, i want to add a variable label to my axis for nplot?
I also want to know if it's possible to add variable like sizevar and colorvar of gvisBubbleChart to nplot ?

Thank you.

```
library(rCharts)
VehiculeFunction <- function(data, gamme, absciss, ordinate){

  # Aim: Permet de visualiser les données sous la forme de nuages de points 
  #      croisant GMF*Coût,  Ratio K * Ratio Coût ou bien GMF*Ratio en 
  #      choisissant la gamme qu'on désire
  # Input: data.frame avec notamment GAMME, PROJET, PERIMETRE, NITG, GMF.24,
  #        Cout.24 et libele
  # Output: Graphique avec le croisement choisi ainsi que le libellé étiquetté
  #         sur le point qu'on voudra identifier

  if(absciss == "GMF.24"){
    my.data <- data[data$RANG_NITG_PROJET_K %in% c(1, 2, 3),]
  } else if(absciss == "Ratio.K") {
    my.data <- data[data$RANG_NITG_PROJET_C %in% c(1, 2, 3),]
  }
  my.data2 <- my.data[my.data$GAMME == gamme,]
  X <- my.data2[[absciss]] 
  Y <- my.data2[[ordinate]] 
  SIZEVAR <- my.data2$Ratio.K
  df <- data.frame(X,Y,SIZEVAR)

  plot <- nPlot(x = "X", y = "Y", size = "SIZEVAR", data = df, type = "scatterChart")
  plot$xAxis(axisLabel = 'X')
  plot 
}


VehiculeFunction(data.vehicule, gamme = "M1", "GMF.24", "Cout.24")
```

Comment: For example here i want  plot$xAxis(axisLabel = 'absciss')

Comment: Please give a reproducible example. What is `data.vehicule`

Comment: data.vehicule is a dataframe of 18 variables and 36 000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Usage:

```
gvisBubbleChart(data, idvar = "", xvar = "", yvar = "",
                  colorvar = "", sizevar = "",
                  options = list(), chartid)
```

E.G.

```
 ## Set color and size
 bubble2 <- gvisBubbleChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", xvar="Sales", yvar="Expenses",
                      colorvar="Location", sizevar="Profit",
                      options=list(hAxis='{minValue:75, maxValue:125}'))
```

SEE http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/googleVis/docs/gvisBubbleChart

Comment: yes i'm agree with this, but is it possible to do that with nplot (rChart)?

Comment: have you tried using google motion charts? http://code.google.com/p/google-motion-charts-with-r/

Comment: Yes i tried it's work nicely, but want to use rchat which i prefer.